# jpgrid php json_encode() associative array

Tags: php, jqgrid, associative-array, json

i just started using jpgrid. I am having this issue with php json_encode.

according to the example from the jqgrid website, the json string can be generated by php codes like the following:

```
    $responce->page = "1";
    $responce->total = 1;
    $responce->records = "1";

    $i=1; $amttot=0; $taxtot=0; $total=0;
    while($i<=10) {
        $amttot += $row[amount];
        $taxtot += $row[tax];
        $total += $row[total];
        $responce->rows[$i]['id']=strval($i);
        $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array("123","2012-10-15","name","10000","tax","9999","note");
        $i++;
    }
    $responce->rows = (array)$responce->rows;
    $responce->userdata['amount'] = $amttot;
    $responce->userdata['tax'] = $taxtot;
    $responce->userdata['total'] = $total;
    $responce->userdata['name'] = 'Totals:';
```

i am having problem with

```
    $responce->rows[$i]['id']=strval($i);
    $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array("123","2012-10-15","name","10000","tax","9999","note");
```

when php json_encode produce the json string, the rows array is treated as an associative array. hence the result json string looks like:

```
{"page":"1","total":1,"records":"1",
 "rows":{"1":{"id":"1","cell":["123","2012-10-15","name","10000","tax","9999","note"]},
         "2":{"id":"2","cell":["123","2012-10-15","name","10000","tax","9999","note"]},
         "3":{"id":"3","cell":["123","2012-10-15","name","10000","tax","9999","note"]},
         "4":{"id":"4","cell":["123","2012-10-15","name","10000","tax","9999","note"]},
         "5":{"id":"5","cell":["123","2012-10-15","name","10000","tax","9999","note"]},
         "6":{"id":"6","cell":["123","2012-10-15","name","10000","tax","9999","note"]},
         "7":{"id":"7","cell":["123","2012-10-15","name","10000","tax","9999","note"]},
         "8":{"id":"8","cell":["123","2012-10-15","name","10000","tax","9999","note"]},
         "9":{"id":"9","cell":["123","2012-10-15","name","10000","tax","9999","note"]},
         "10":{"id":"10","cell":["123","2012-10-15","name","10000","tax","9999","note"]}},
 "userdata":{"amount":0,"tax":0,"total":0,"name":"Totals:"}}
```

this json string can not be processed by jqgrid. in fact jqgrid doesn't raise any javascript error. it just doesnt render the table content. i had a look the json string from the jqgrid example website via firebugs. it looks like this:

```
{"page":"1","total":2,"records":"13",
 "rows":[{"id":"13","cell":["13","2007-10-06","Client 3","1000.00","0.00","1000.00",null]},
         {"id":"12","cell":["12","2007-10-06","Client 2","700.00","140.00","840.00",null]},
         {"id":"11","cell":["11","2007-10-06","Client 1","600.00","120.00","720.00",null]},
         {"id":"10","cell":["10","2007-10-06","Client 2","100.00","20.00","120.00",null]},          
         {"id":"9","cell":["9","2007-10-06","Client 1","200.00","40.00","240.00",null]},
         {"id":"8","cell":["8","2007-10-06","Client 3","200.00","0.00","200.00",null]},
         {"id":"7","cell":["7","2007-10-05","Client 2","120.00","12.00","134.00",null]}, 
         {"id":"6","cell":["6","2007-10-05","Client 1","50.00","10.00","60.00",""]},
         {"id":"5","cell":["5","2007-10-05","Client 3","100.00","0.00","100.00","no tax at all"]},
         {"id":"4","cell":["4","2007-10-04","Client 3","150.00","0.00","150.00","no tax"]}],
        "userdata":{"amount":3220,"tax":342,"total":3564,"name":"Totals:"}}
```

I can not figure out how can the php sample code which uses the associate array to generate such an array obj inside a json string. i am using php 5.4

what can i change either in jqgrid or php to make this work? i am surprised no one else had this problem. i may be missing something rather obvious.

thanks

casbby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by how the response array object is generated in PHP. When I originally created the array in a loop I started the index from 1 instead of 0. 
       Response->rows[i]
This caused php to treat the response array to be associative rather than sequential. Hence php puts the name value objects in the response object (while I was trying to create an array of non-named objects)

The solution is to make sure the array index is sequential and continuous